# Copying/sync'ing case sensitive files into a folder on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, perforce, case-sensitive

I just discovered we can turn on per directory case sensitivity on Windows 10 and that one needs to recursively enable this feature on every child directory so everything under the root folder supports case sensitivity. This is fine if I had a pre-existing directory tree I suppose.

But what if I had an existing codebase, with a set of subdirectories and files that has case sensitive names, which is hosted on a remote system (e.g. a perforce case-sensitive server) that I want to copy over to a root folder on Windows 10 that I have enabled case sensitivity on? Can I (perforce) sync first to download the codebase into the root folder and then run a recursive command (as shown here [Apply setCaseSensitiveInfo recursively to all folders and subfolders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51591091/apply-setcasesensitiveinfo-recursively-to-all-folders-and-subfolders)) to enable case sensitivity so editors can correctly open files that just differ in case? Will that work? If not how can I achieve this?

P.S. This is the first time I'm posting here so please let me know if this question appears ambiguous in any way and I'll do my best to edit/re-post.

P.P.S. Also I'm in the middle of a transition from a Macbook to a Windows laptop and as such do not have a windows machine to try this on for myself, so I ask this question to gain understanding, that will aid in the setup of a development environment on a Windows machine. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got my hands on a windows machine to test this behavior and I can confirm that cloning/sync'ing a repository with a subdirectory tree containing case sensitive files and folders, into a root folder that has the case sensitivity attribute enabled will work and applications are able to open these files correctly subsequently; the key concept here is case-sensitivity inheritance for new children!

Sure enough, I later found this article explaining the feature: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/improved-per-directory-case-sensitivity-support-in-wsl/#case-sensitivity-inheritance